# Is there a bug in MatrixExp in Mathematica v10?

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to compute

```
MatrixExp[-I t {{0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 
1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}}]
```

With ver 9 the result is nice with Sin's and Cos's.
In ver 10 the result is a mess with Sin's, Cos's, Sinh's, Cosh's, and root's!
The two results aren't even equal with a random value of t!

Can anyone please verify this?

Comment: I see the same thing as you!

Comment: Confirmed the issue in ver.10. For your example specifically, since the matrix can be exactly diagonalized using `Eigensystem`, you can get a nice analytic expression--I'm assuming it's used in quantum mechanics where the matrix is the Hamiltonian (easily diagonalized in your example) and you want the unitary propagator with `MatrixExp`.

Comment: Yeah, the changes made to the underlying methods put us a step backward for this example. Not a bug (per response by @Nasser) but not a great outcome either. I'll see about making adjustments. One workaround for now is to use `-t` as multiplier (with no `I` factor), and afterwards do the replacement `t->I*t`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll look forward to another update to ver 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is the same. V10 presentation is just went wrong somewhere, but it is the same value as v9.

I copied v9 result to v10 and compared the real and the imaginary parts.

```
Clear[t];
expr = {{0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 1/2, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}};
v10 = MatrixExp[-I t expr];
v9 = (*copied from v9 notebook, too large to post *)
v10Real = ComplexExpand@Re@N@v10;
v9Real = ComplexExpand@Re@N@v9;
Grid[{{Plot[v9Real, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "V9 real"],
   Plot[v10Real, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "v10 real"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
v10Im = ComplexExpand@Im@N@v10;
v9Im = ComplexExpand@Im@N@v9;
Grid[{{Plot[v9Im, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "V9 Im"],
   Plot[v10Im, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "v10 Im"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As to why V10 representation is not as nice as V9, I would not know. But the answer to your question if there is a bug, then no. And since they are the same values, in theory one can now convert V10 result to appear in the same form as V9.